# How to add links to gridview in asp.net vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Here is what I have so far. Gridview is data bind using vb.net code behind.

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href='<%# String.Format("Details.aspx#{0}", Eval("RideID"))%>' runat="server" >Link</a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

and this is the result I get

[image]

But what I really want is to have the rideID as the hyper link (see bellow), and not adding a new column called link

How can I get the value of the RideID into the anchor tag in the itemtemplate?

or what is the best way to make rideID as the hyperlink?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can do this:

```
<a href='<%# String.Format("Details.aspx#{0}", Eval("RideID"))%>' runat="server" ><%# Eval("RideID") %></a>
```

Comment: Yep, this should pretty much do it.

Comment: yes. I swear I tried that. It didn't work before but it works now! thanks Phil

Comment: Hi Phil, I now have a duplicate column. RideID column has a merge cell sub routine in VB.net. I  need to hide the RideID column and I need to Merge column of the link if the value is the same. Can you help with that? Thanks

Comment: @BobNoobGuy - You will need to post a new question and someone will take a look